# How to override filters.js in to custom theme?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

How to override 
`vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/filters/filters.js` into custom theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution of this, you need to create the module for the same.
follow steps.

1. Create `requirejs-config.js` under `<Namespace>\<Module>\view\base\requirejs-config.js` with below code.

   ```
   var config = {
     "map": {
       "*": {
         "Magento_Ui/js/grid/filters/filters": 
             "<Namespace>_<Module>/js/grid/filters/filters"
       }
     }
    };
   ```
2. override `filter.js` to below path.

   ```
   <Namespace>\<Module>\view\base\web\js\grid\filters\filters.js
   ```

Done the overriding :)

Answer (score 0):

In your theme folder create

```
Magento_Ui/web/js/grid/filters/
```

and add your new *filters.js* to that dir.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the logic in the path above, the custom theme path would be something like:

```
app/design/frontend/CustomVendor/theme-custom/Magento_Ui/web/js/grid/filters/filters.js
```

the base folder can be overwritten just like the frontend folder in your custom theme but becouse your custom theme is already a pure frontend theme we skip the `view/base/` part

Comment: this is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via a module. Assume it's called Example. Now you can follow these steps :

**1** Create requirejs-config.js under  **Test/Example/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js** add this

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/filters/filters':'Test_Example/view/base/web/js/grid/filters/filters'
    }
}
```

};

**2** create the file **Test/Example/view/base/web/js/grid/filters/filters.js** with your content.
For testing you can add a console.log in your new file filters.js.
Don't forget to clean the cache and to regenerate public resources.

Good luck !!! Happy Coding !!!

Comment: Hi there thanks for the help but this also doesn't work, have you tried it in your source? or am I missing something?